# how to remove blank space at top of details section in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am working on a crystal report where my contents are in the details section. the report looks fine in the design part, but when I take a print, I get extra white space in the top. how to remove it ???

[my print copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEuhx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If that space is simply the Report header, suppress that section.

But most likely it's simply the page margin.  To adjust that, go to File, Page Setup...